# What is wrong with my Flow Interview?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, compile-error

I am working on including a `Flow` via `Custom Button`, and so I created a `Visualforce Page` which includes a `<flow:interview>` component and references a `Flow.Interview` on an extension.

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="MyExtension">
    <flow:interview name="My_Flow_Unique_Name" interview="{!interview}"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public Flow.Interview interview { get; private set; }
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>
        {
            'caseId' => controller.getId()
        };
        interview = new Flow.Interview.My_Flow_Unique_Name(inputs);
        interview.start();
    }
}
```

When I try to save the page, the Developer Console prevents me from doing so. Unfortunately, the error message is blank so it is not clear what I'm doing wrong.

[image: FlowDemo blank error]

If I remove the `interview="{!interview}"` attribute specification, the page compiles. But I need to set this attribute so I can provide the proper inputs. What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `public Flow.Interview interview { get; private set; }`

to

```
public Flow.Interview.My_Flow_Unique_Name interview { get; private set; }
```

The VF page saves after compilation in developer console.